# Create a log file and read it using Objective-C in iOS Simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am creating a multiplayer game and I am looking for a way to store an array in a file like you would in other languages. technically I want to specify a file to dump an array into a file and then read it as an array.

For example, in PHP there are the var_dump() , var_export() or print_r() functions. Perl has the Data Dumper CPAN class, etc etc.

is there a way to do the same in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.

`[yourNSArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: and how can I retrieve the array from the file?? is there an easy automatic way?

Comment: Yes, [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; See this: `http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfFile:`